# C++ Compiler Error when trying to link two files together

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am justing wondering what the error means here if anyone can help me.

```
g++ -o Try2 student.o studentlist.o
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
main                                /usr/local/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.8.4/crt1.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to Try2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you first compile the two source files with `g++ -c student.cpp` and `g++ -c studentlist.o`?

Comment: Please also show the files

Comment: @Tony Tannous Yeah I did.

Comment: @Aryan Parekh Both of the .cpp files are around the 300 lines of code and the header are pretty long but i'll try to post them

Comment: @Swkn The problem can come from anywhere, try to remove segments of code and see if it suddenly solves the problem. Basically, try making a [mre]. You might find out the reason on your own

Comment: @AryanParekh Oh I got what you're saying, I'll be trying that shorty. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does one of your files contain a `main` function?

Comment: @AlanBirtles no I don't have a main function in either.

Comment: What are you trying to build? If its an executable you need a main function if it isn't you need to either tell gcc you want a static library or use ar to create a static lib